# How do I absolutely ensure that a Phusion Passenger instance stays alive?

Tags: ruby, apache, timeout, passenger, centos

I'm having a problem where no matter what I try all Passenger instances are destroyed after an idle period (5 minutes, but sometimes longer). I've read the Passenger docs and related questions/answers on Stack Overflow.

My global config looks like this:

```
PassengerMaxPoolSize 6
PassengerMinInstances 1
PassengerPoolIdleTime 300
```

And my virtual config:

```
PassengerMinInstances 1
```

The above should ensure that at least one instance is kept alive after the idle timeout. I'd like to avoid setting PassengerPoolIdleTime to 0 as I'd like to clean up all but one idle instance.

I've also added the ruby binary to my CSF ignore list to prevent the long running process from being culled.

Is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be quite a common problem for people running Apache on WHM/cPanel:

http://techiezdesk.wordpress.com/2011/01/08/apache-graceful-restart-requested-every-two-hours/

Enabling piped logging sorted the problem out for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the PassengerMinInstances to anything other than 1 like 3 and see that work?

Comment: Thanks, will try that out and report back.

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer for you on this link: http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/browse_thread/thread/7557f8ef0ff000df/62f5c42aa1fe5f7e .  Look at the last comment by Phusion guy.

> Is there a way to ensure that I always have 10 processes up and
> running, and that each process only serves 500 requests before being
> shut down?
>
> "Not at this time. But the current behavior is such that the next time
> it determines that more processes need to be spawned it will make sure
> L at least PassengerMinInstances processes exist."

I have to say their documentation doesn't seem to match what the current behavior.

Comment: Thanks, but that is a different issue to mine. That person has PassengerMaxRequests - which shuts down processes after serving a certain number of requests and is used for applications with memory leaks. I do not have PassengerMaxRequests included in my config. However, thanks for pointing me to the mailing list, I will post my question over there.